# What character can be used in a SCSS/SASS function and variable name?

Tags: function, sass

What characters can be used in SCSS/SASS function names and variable names? I want to know especially which non-alphabets like `_`, `-`, numbers, punctuations, etc. can be used.

Comment: @cimmanon I can't parse your comment. Is that a sentence?

Comment: @Joe I want to know not only about variables but also about functions. Your linked question does not have that.

Comment: Do you mean functions or mixins?

Comment: @Joe I wrote functions. Why are you asking whether I am mentioning mixins?

Comment: To check, because many people get confused between functions and mixins. Hold on to your hair :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#variable_and_mixin_names

The current version of SASS is 3.4.5 (Sep 19, 2014). As of version 3.0.0, the following is true:

> SassScript variable and mixin names may now contain hyphens. In fact, they may be any valid CSS3 identifier. For example:
>
> ```
> $prettiest-color: #542FA9
> =pretty-text
>   color: $prettiest-color
> ```

There's [no mention of any restrictions on function names](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions) in the official documentation, and from the source it appears to not do any kind of error-checking whatsoever. A "valid function name" appears to be completely undocumented.